# Why does Ubuntu throw an I/O error randomly?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, io, can-bus

I have got a PC/104 (its OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.19.89 xenomai3) that is connected to two motors via two CAN adapters. Few days back, I wrote some simple code to open my PC/104's CAN ports using the [libpcanfd](https://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/files/PCAN-Driver-Linux_UserMan_eng.pdf) library.

My project folder observes the following hierarchy:

> - **io_error_debug**
>
>   - build
>   - include (empty)
>   - src
>
>     - *CMakeLists.txt*
>     - *main.cpp*
>   - CMakeLists.txt

`CMakeLists.txt` at `/root`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(io_error_debug)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) # add before adding subdirectory
add_subdirectory (src)
add_executable(io_error_debug src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(io_error_debug /usr/lib/libpcanfd.so    # pcan
"-Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,@/usr/xenomai/lib/cobalt.wrappers -Wl,@/usr/xenomai   /lib/modechk.wrappers  /usr/xenomai/lib/xenomai/bootstrap-pic.o  -L/usr/xenomai/lib    -lcobalt -lmodechk -lpthread -lrt"
)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` under `/src`:

```
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <lcm/lcm_coretypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pcanfd.h>
#include <libpcanfd.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fd;
    fd = pcanfd_open("/dev/pcan0", OFD_BITRATE  | PCANFD_INIT_STD_MSG_ONLY | OFD_NONBLOCKING, 1000000);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Open operation failed with err %d on port no. %s\n",fd, "/dev/pcan0");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("Open succeeded with return value %d on port no. %s\n",fd, "/dev/pcan0");
    }   
}
```

The code compiles and executes well when the motors are switched on. However, when I switch off the motors and switch them on again, I get the following error after executing my code:

> Open operation failed with err -5 on port no. /dev/pcan0

Furthermore, `dmesg` shows these suspicious error lines when I run my code:

> [16900.914132] pcan: set_normal_mode(CAN1) failed (err -5)
>
> [16900.914162] pcan: can't open device hardware itself (err -5)!

The [documentation](https://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/files/PCAN-Driver-Linux_UserMan_eng.pdf) states that `-5` is an `errno` error. Therefore, I looked for the value `-5` in this [errno errors' list](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-error-codes/) and I found out that it is`I/O error`. Interestingly, when I switch off the PC/104 and execute my code, the program runs well. Nevertheless, when I repeat the aforementioned operation (i.e., switching off and on the motors) I will encounter the same error. I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: Have you checked your system logs and/or `dmesg`?  I/O errors are often logged there.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have executed dmesg. I have got the following error messages linked to CAN:
[16900.914132] pcan: set_normal_mode(CAN1) failed (err -5)

[16900.914162] pcan: can't open device hardware itself (err -5)!

I have updated my post accordingly

Comment: This really sounds like a hardware problem. For example if your CAN adapters aren't grounded with the motors, the ground potential will go haywire, particularly during motor on/off when there's high ground currents. Missing bus terminators could also cause intermittent problems. Check the actual CAN bus: do you get error frames? If so then it's likely because the bus is incorrectly wired.

Comment: @Lundin Many thanks. I see. I am going to check out the wiring.